# Strange behaviour of strlen

Tags: c++

I made a program in C++ in which I used two char arrays which i initialize at time of declaration and when I used `strlen()` function for calculating their lengths I got strange outputs. The code is shown below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

char consonant[] = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char vowel[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};



int main()
{
    int lenv, lenc;
    lenc = strlen(consonant);
    lenv = strlen(vowel);
    printf("lenv = %d and lenc = %d\n", lenv, lenc);
    return 0;
}
```

the output for above program when run on ideone is

```
lenv = 26 and lenc = 21
```

and when runs on windows using codeblocks is

```
lenv = 5 and lenc = 26
```

Please tell me the reason for such strange behaviour...

Comment: Talk about "strange behavior"... The title says C. The code is written in C. So why is there a C++ tag?

Comment: `using namespace std;` and `<string>` make it C++...

Comment: Because this code is a gender-bender.  Note the `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`

Comment: Don't forget the terminating nul character `'\0'`...

Comment: Pfft, that doesn't qualify as C++ at all. It's a C question with a couple unrelated lines of code thrown in.

Comment: If the C compiler won't compile it, it's not C.

Comment: Then may I argue that the OP should use `std::string`s and `length()` or `size()`, as well as `std::cout`?

Comment: Yeah, because no one ever posts code in a question that won't compile. Oh wait... The point is, if he wants to write a program in C (which is what the title says), the question should have a C tag. It's obviously not a C++ program, otherwise he'd be using `std::string` and there'd be no question to ask.

Comment: Rather than arguing pointlessly, how about you fix the question so it makes sense.  i.e. make the WHOLE question consistent.

Comment: I could rewrite all the code in VB and add that tag. Would that make everyone happy?

Comment: I'd revert it because it would more or less render any answers useless to the asker.

Comment: I don't understand this stance that people take.  C and C++ share a common subset.  Why is it that when someone presents code within that subset, and calls it C++, everyone declares it mis-tagged C?  Can the opposite argument not also be made?  That is, if the OP tags it C, can you not just as validly declare it mis-tagged C++?  Of course not, in either case. If you need clarification about what language s/he is actually interested in, ask. Don't just change the language tag, thereby possibly preventing people from seeing the question who might have information relevant *only* to C++.

Answer (score 12):

No strange behavior here. Your strings are not nul-terminated, so there's no way for the `strlen()` function to identify where they end.

When you initialize your string like this:

```
char consonant[] = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
```

There's no nul char added. You can either make it a string (the double-quotes cause the compiler to automatically append the nul terminator):

```
char consonant[] = "bcd...z";
```

or you can include it yourself explicitly at the end of the array:

```
char consonant[] = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '\0'};
```

Otherwise, `strlen()` will happily read off the end of your array until it happens to find a byte somewhere in memory with a value of 0.

Comment: Undefined could be considered strange :)

Answer (score 8):

`strlen` can only be used on a string and not an arbitrary array of characters.

> The strlen() function shall compute the number of bytes in the **string** to which s points, not including the terminating null byte. -- IEEE1003

The C++ standard says that `strlen` is C++ is identical to `strlen` in C. The C standard says:

> The `strlen` function computes the length of the **string** pointed to by *s*. -- C99 7.21.6.3

And:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
>   character. -- C99 7.1.1

So you must ensure that whatever you pass to `strlen` is in fact a *string*, not just an array of characters.

Comment: In fact, "an array of characters" is an string. In C, this is the way u usually define a string: `char str[] = {"Test"};`
But there's nothing wrong if you define each character on its own, as long as u don't forget the terminating 0-character. He forgot the Ascii-0, but I would still call it a string (although the end of string is outside his buffer)

Comment: @maja David's post makes it **abundantly clear** that there's a distinction between a string and an array of characters. All strings are arrays of characters but not all arrays of characters are strings. As for what *you* would call things, that is irrelevant. What the standard calls things is what's important.

Comment: @NikBougalis: I agree, but if you want to really split hairs, then I think not all strings are arrays of characters in the sense that an array is a *type*, hence why the standard uses "contiguous sequence of characters" and "*first* null character". For instance, `char myarray[6] = {'a', 'b', '\0', 'c', 'd', '\0'};` creates two *strings*, but only a single *array* has been created.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: splitting hairs is good - I used the term 'array' as a shortcut for 'contiguous sequence'; while that's accurate, using it in a discussion dealing with standard legalese was probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis  Because of "splitting hairs is good":
I'm not sure about it, but if this is the definition: "contiguous sequence of characters" and "first null character", than you can still call it a string, can't you?. The null-character is outside of the variable-memory-space, but there is a 0 later in the ram, actually the next 0-char is still in the program's memory-space.  Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @maja: You're wrong. "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and **including** the first null character."

Comment: @Nik Bougalis ok you won ^^

Comment: @maja: The C standard also has no idea how your memory is laid out, or what's in it. While it may all be bits and bytes to your computer, it's not to C. The only way you get a "contiguous sequence of characters" in C is if you do something in your C program that guarantees you get that, like defining a `char` array. Once you overstep that, all bets are off. You can't point to whatever random garbage might happen to exist in your RAM and try to claim it's a conforming C string.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already noted that you should close your c-style string with '\0' and your `lenc=21` is most probably for some overflow phenomenon (it can be n*SIZE_MAX+21 with any n...).

To focus on *how you can solve your problem properly* in c:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

char consonant[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"; /* this is automatically '\0' terminated */
char vowel[] = "aeiou";

int main()
{
    int lenv, lenc;
    lenc = strlen(consonant);
    lenv = strlen(vowel);
    printf("lenv = %d and lenc = %d\n", lenv, lenc);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `using namespace std` is c++ only.

On the other hand *a proper c++ solution* looks like this:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

std::string consonant("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"); 
std::string vowel("aeiou");

int main()
{
    using namespace std; // if you wish using it, put it into a function

    int lenc = consonant.size();
    int lenv = vowel.size();
    cout << "lenv = " << lenc << " and " << "lenc = " << lenc << endl;
    return 0;
}
```